# Python ImportError: No module named 'funds'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cloned a repo from [github](https://github.com/utkarshohm/mf-platform-bse)

I keep getting this error when I try running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import api.py
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\mf\mf-platform-bse\mf-platform-bse\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from models.transactions import TransactionBSE, TransactionXsipBSE, TransResponseBSE, Transaction, PaymentLinkBSE
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\mf\mf-platform-bse\mf-platform-bse\models\transactions.py", line 4, in <module>
    from funds import SchemePlan, FundScheme
ImportError: No module named 'funds'
```

Here is my folder structure inside the models folder

[image]

Comment: So do `from models.funds import *`?

Comment: This is a Python 2 project.

Comment: and? This would work the same in py2

Comment: @nosklo: Python 2 has implicit relative imports.

Comment: If this is a Python 2 project, why is your code tagged python-3.x? If you're trying to use a 3.x-only module in a 2.x program, or vice-versa, that might be the actual problem.

Comment: Meanwhile, is the module actually designed to be dropped into your project and used in-place, instead of installed with `setup.py` or `pip`? If so, do you have all the requirements? Are you maybe supposed to put the whole thing inside a directory and import it via that, or put its top-level directory on your `sys.path`, or something else? (I'd assume there are docs or at least sample code?)

Comment: Also, is `import api.py` really right? That means to import a submodule named `py` from a package named `api`, which is a pretty uncommon thing to do.

Comment: What is that "import api.py" in line 3 of your traceback?

Comment: Taking a quick look at the link: this is a project with only a handful of commits, all a year ago, and few followers, and the docs end with "Need help setting this up or want to contribute? Feel free to raise an issue and I will get back asap". So, have you tried contacting the author, as he suggested, instead of asking random people who've likely never heard of it to help you with what may well be a broken or at least idiosyncratic and poorly documented library?